# MAUI Entry Control Keyboard to accept A TO Z Letters Only

Tags: maui, maui-android

I have a Entry control on MAUI Page to Accept User Name, for this I want the control to Accept A to Z Letters only (no numeric, symbol or special character allowed) and that too in Capital Letters

I wrote xaml like this

```
        <Entry x:Name="txtUserName" Placeholder="User Name" Text="{Binding UserName}" MaxLength="15">
            <Entry.Keyboard>
                <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <KeyboardFlags>CapitalizeCharacter</KeyboardFlags>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </Keyboard>
            </Entry.Keyboard>
        </Entry>
```

this only Capitalizes letters, but numbers and symbols also get accepted, no way to restrict them found.

Comment: You probably need a Behavior or Handler to restrict it natively

Comment: Since this is not necessarily possible on each platform, most developers usually resort to using validation behaviors that check the input and show an error message or similar to the user. For example, on Android you can install different keyboard apps, which all may behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same issue filtering the Text on the TextChanged Function :

```
    private void Letter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
    {
        var textFiltered= new string(e.NewTextValue.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
        ((Entry)sender).Text = textFiltered;
    }
}
```

To implement it will be enough to use insert it in your XAML code the following way

```
        <Entry x:Name="txtUserName" Placeholder="User Name" Text="{Binding UserName}" MaxLength="15" TextChanged="Letter_TextChanged">
        <Entry.Keyboard>
            <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
                <x:Arguments>
                    <KeyboardFlags>CapitalizeCharacter</KeyboardFlags>
                </x:Arguments>
            </Keyboard>
        </Entry.Keyboard>
    </Entry>
```